# Анимация картинки wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Привет Хочу при клике на картинку что бы картинка переворачивалась в низ.Как бы лицом в низ.
Пытался так но выходит что то ваще ужасное

```
private void oneImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var trans = (oneImage.RenderTransform as RotateTransform);
            trans.Angle = 120;
        }
```

вот в XAML код

```
<Image Name="oneImage" MouseDown="oneImage_MouseDown" Stretch="Fill">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"></RotateTransform>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
```

И как задать время что бы например в течение 1 сек это происходило

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Основы анимации](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level15/15_1.php)
- [Анимация трансформаций](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level16/16_1.php)

  ```
  <Button Height="100" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
      <Button.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform />
      </Button.RenderTransform>
      <Button.Template>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Image Source="flower.png"/>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                      <EventTrigger.Actions>
                          <BeginStoryboard>
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                                   By="180" Duration="0:0:1" />
                              </Storyboard>
                          </BeginStoryboard>
                      </EventTrigger.Actions>
                  </EventTrigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Button.Template>
  </Button>
  ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо но надо что бы по оси Y крутилось вокруг себя

Comment: @Санитариум,За это отвечает свойство `RenderTransformOrigin`. Отредактируйте его под свои нужды.

Comment: отлично сапсибо

Comment: @Санитариум, Пожалуйста! Рад, что помог.